# PowerShell "-notlike" comparison is not working with wildcard

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to filter out various user accounts in PowerShell (using the NTFSSecurity module) and it's not working as completely as expected. It is supposed to get an array of `$users` except for the following conditions:

```
$users = Get-NTFSAccess $path | Where-Object {
    $_.Account -ne "DOMAIN\Domain Admins" -and
    $_.Account -ne "Group1" -and
    $_.Account -ne "Group2" -and
    $_.Account -notlike "SecProj_*" -and
    $_.Account -notlike "GRP_SECURE_*"
}
```

The script filtering out `DOMAIN\Domain Admins`, `Group1`, and `Group2`. These groups are defined directly by name.

The script is NOT filtering out `SecProj_*` and `GRP_SECURE_*`.

Am I using the wildcard (`*`) correctly in the `-notlike` statement?

Comment: Syntax looks fine to me. Any chance there is something at the beginning, and `*SecProj_*` is required?

Comment: Unless it's expecting something like DOMAIN\SecProj_* there's nothing in front of the 2 groups I'm using the wildcard on.

Comment: That's possible; can't comment without the output data. I suggest you give it a go. `_` should be fine, but I would reduce to `*SecProj*` if it's not essential.

Comment: Cheers @gms0ulman adding * at the beginning of the string worked. Thank you!